# Python MYSQL How can I loop through a selection?

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

I'm trying to build a soccer database with MySQL. I made a selection, which contains the teams, and I want to loop through them on a another selection, so I don't have write 18 different selection. Can you help me, where did I make the mistake? I keep getting errors.

```
k = 0

#Teams in one list
my_sq7 = "SELECT Team FROM bundesligatabella_2020_2021"
my_cursor.execute(my_sq7)
result3 = my_cursor.fetchall()

for row in result3:
    my_sq9 = "SELECT SUM(Home_scored) FROM bundesliga_2020_2021_2 WHERE Home = %s"
    my_cursor.executemany(my_sq9, result3[k][0])
    result4 = my_cursor.fetchall()
    k += 1
```

I also want to save the result in another list, to update another column.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python\database.py", line 141, in <module>
    my_cursor.executemany(my_sq9, result3[k][0])
  File "Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 675, in executemany
    self.execute(operation, params)
  File "Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 651, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 538, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are doing `for row in result3:`, then there is no need to index the elements of `result3` using indexing.
2. `executemany` expects *all* the values at once. But you can't use that for a SELECT statement; you will just return the results of the last SELECT.
3. But the real problem, I believe, is: The second argument to `execute` or `executemany` needs to be a `list` or `tuple` (or some iterable). In the case of `executemany`, it needs to be, for example, a list of lists. You seemed to have been passing neither of these.

So:

```
result3 = my_cursor.fetchall()
my_sq9 = "SELECT SUM(Home_scored) FROM bundesliga_2020_2021_2 WHERE Home = %s"
result4 = []
for row in result3:
    my_cursor.execute(my_sq9, (row[0],))
    result4.append(my_cursor.fetchone())
```

Have you considered getting what you want with the following:

```
SELECT Team, SUM(Home_scored) FROM bundesligatabella_2020_2021
GROUP BY Team
```

**Correction:**

```
SELECT Team, SUM(Home_scored) FROM
bundesligatabella_2020_2021 t1 JOIN bundesliga_2020_2021_2 t2 on t1.Team = t2.Home
GROUP BY Team
```

Comment: thank you so much, I did not know about this GROUP BY function, first I had a fear, that it won't work if I have stored one season in one table, so I have multiple time the same team, but it works :)

Comment: I was a list hasty and didn't notice that you were dealing with two separate. I have posted what I think is now the correct SQL to get the desired results with one SQL request.